# Golang implementing database funcs using interfaces

Tags: database, go, interface

Sorry for a bit dummy questions, but I'm kinda stuck.

So, I'm implementing wrapper above database driver for my application, and I need to keep it as portable as possible.
I came to decision that interfaces are perfect match for this task. So, I have my database struct with some variables and app-specific methods, and two interface functions:

```
query(request string) error
flush() int? string?? struct?? slice????, error
```

Now you probably got the main question. How do I do return data that type "flush()" doesn't know? Can I return it by interface, and if I can, how to work with that?

Second question is pretty basic, but still it isn't clear to me.
So, I have this database struct with two methods designed to be implemented by package user to use db driver he want. 
Ho do I write it and how future implementation will look (there is an example on tour of go, but it's about interface for different structs with similar methods)
Hope you'll help me find an understanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, flush can just have the signiture;

```
flush() interface{}, error
```

How do you implement? Something like this with reasonable method bodies should do it for you;

```
type MyDbDriver struct {
     //fields
}

func (d *MyDbDriver) query(request string) error {
     return nil
}

func (d *MyDbDriver) flush() interface{}, error {
      return nil, nil
}
```

In Go all interface implementations are implicit, meaning, if your type has methods that match the interfaces signature, then you've implemented it. No need for something like `public class MyType: IMyInterface, IThisIsntCSharp`. Note that in the example above `*MyDbDriver` has implemented your interface but `MyDbDriver` has not.

Edit: below a some pseudo calling code;

```
e := driver.query("select * from thatTable where ThatProperty = 'ThatValue'")
if e != nil {
    return nil, e
}

i, err := driver.flush()
if err != nil {
     return nil, err
}

MyConcreteInstance := i.(MyConcreteType)
// note that this will panic if the type of i is not MyConcreteType
// that can be avoided with the familiar object, err calling syntax
MyConcreteIntance, ok := i.(MyConcreteType)
if !ok {
      // the type of i was not MyConcreteType :\
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it still isn't clear how to handle this returns in caller function. Of cause, I know what type I wanna get with SQL request, but surely it's gonna be necessary to check what type was returned. How can I do this type of errorchecking?

Comment: @mersinvald in the calling code you would typically use a 'type assertion' or 'type switch' to unbox the data. I'll edit with an example of this (for a developer it works much like a cast though conceptually/internally it's a bit different). The concept is covered here in the language spec https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions